# phpword, listtype with dash or an unordered list

Tags: php, list, phpword, unordered

I would like to use dashes as listtypes instead of bullets or square is it possible?

something like

```
- yes
- no
- nes
- yo
```

I am working with phpword and generate 'docx'-files

Comment: This can be controlled thru css?

Comment: i am using phpword

Answer (score -1):

**Use Before in css for that**

```html
<style type="text/css">
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  li:before {
    content: " - ";
  }
</style>
<ul class="bullet">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```